# Different results when testing if remote UNC path exists in a for/foreach loop

Tags: powershell, batch-file, foreach, exists

When attempting to loop through a collection of ~3k machines to check if a folder path exists, both Test-Path (PowerShell) and 'IF EXIST' (Batch) return bogus results, saying that a remote path does not exist when it **does**, in fact, exist.
I'm running the PowerShell session and ISE (and Command Prompt) 'As An Administrator' with different authoritative domain creds than my user login account. I've supplied the -Credential parameter to Test-Path with no change in the results.

I'm running Win10 v1709 (10.0.16299.547) and PowerShell v5.1.16299.547.

---

When running the commands by themselves on a one-off machine name, they work:

Powershell:

```
Test-Path "\\machineName\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name"
```

Batch:

```
IF EXIST "\\machineName\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name" (echo True)
```

Both of the above examples return 'True' as expected.

---

However, when using these commands in for/foreach loops, I only get 'False' results :(

PowerShell:

```
$Computers = Get-Content c:\logs\computers.txt
Write-Output "Checking $($Computers.count) Machines ..."
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    if (Test-Path "\\$Computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name")
    {
        Write-Output "$($Computer): Folder Exists"
    }
}
```

Batch:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (C:\logs\computers.txt) do (
    echo | SET /P nonewline=Checking %%i ...
    IF EXIST "\\%%i\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name" (
        echo  Found
        echo %%i >> c:\logs\folder_exists.txt
    ) ELSE (echo .)
)
pause
```

Both of these examples return **nothing**.

Where do I start looking for what could be causing this undesirable behavior?
Are there GPOs that might cause this result, that are applied from my domain?

Comment: You have at least two lines of invalid syntax in your batch file.  If you read the help for the `IF` command you should see that your `IF...ELSE` syntax is incorrect.  Also  the line that begins with `%%i` should throw a syntax error because I am pretty sure the computer name is not a valid command.

Comment: Are you sure? I've used this syntax successfully in the past, and the syntax **does** work correctly when supplied as a single command, outside the for loop. I've updated the output into the file with an echo prefix, but even without that part working, nothing is output to the Command Prompt.

Comment: Where's the mistake? Here's the Microsoft help page: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `IF /?`. In regards to the link you posted you should be able to see it clear as day.  Third and fourth example.

Comment: These recommendations are not helpful if you are seeing a clear syntax error. Call out the apparent mistake already. More importantly to the question, **how would that be causing the command to fail** within a for loop?

Comment: @Squashman `IF EXIST` is a valid syntax.

Comment: @JohnKens, never said it wasn't.  The code had the `IF ...ELSE` syntax wrong.  That has now been corrected.

Comment: I had placed the ELSE on a new line, but it was a pointless contention that would **not** have impacted the problem being described in this question.

Comment: @Squashman `IF exist "file.txt" (Echo it exists) ELSE (Echo It's Missing)` Works fine for me. It might be the layout you have it formatted in mike. I would check your for statment and see if that file even exists.

Comment: @JohnKens, exactly.  That is the correct syntax for putting it on one line.  Go and look back at the edits to the question.  The `ELSE` was on a separate line.  It cannot be on a separate line.  It needs to be on the same line as the right parentheses.

Comment: @Squashman Yeah I saw you recently edited the response, looks solid now.

Comment: @JohnKens That works for me too, what I'm trying to understand is why using the same syntax within a for loop **does not** work.

Comment: @mike425, the only other possible problem with your code would be if the input file has any spaces in the computer names.  If all the computer names are on a separate line without any spaces then the code is fine.  If the path exists but is saying it is not, then it becomes a system configuration or permissions problem with the destination computer.

Comment: @Squashman That minor syntax issue was not the problem. Do you have any insight into why this wouldn't be working in a for loop?

Comment: I manage 6 servers at work.  Your code works fine with all my servers.  But I also know two facts. 1) My user is part of the administrators group on all the servers. 2) I know that all the administrative shares are enabled.

Comment: All the computer names are indeed on a separate line without any spaces. I've written similar scripts a hundred times. I'm not understanding why this isn't working in a new (to me) work domain environment. Ideas on those configuration/permission issues, when **one-off commands in the same session are working**? If this was a permission issue, the one-off commands would be failing too, right? Yet the commands work as expected **outside** of the for/foreach loops.

Comment: @mike425 as a tip that may help you, use `for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (` for the `for` statment. If your computer names have spaces in them you wont be able to read them off the file.

Comment: @JohnKens There are no spaces in any of the computer names. This is such an easy/routine procedure, I'm stumped as to why it isn't working as I'm expecting.

Comment: @mike425 Try breaking it down, echo'ing the final computer-name of the %%i. Check to see if it's actually your computer-name. Then break the For statements (Put 1 PC in the text file). See what part of the code is broken. I don't have an environment to test such a batch but I can tell you that as it stands it should work.

Comment: @JohnKens I have broken the code down, and have validated that each component is working. I'm stumped because this exact syntax and approach has worked for me before, in a different domain environment.

Comment: Two debugging things I would try.  As the first command in your `FOR` loop do this: `pushd \\%%i\C$`. Then on the next line: `CALL echo Pushd Error: %%errorlevel%%` and the last line inside your `FOR` command put a `POPD`.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371896/declined-rude-or-abusive-flags)

Comment: I've submitted an answer to my question. Thanks to you both for your troubleshooting suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch resolution:
Opened the text file in Notepad++, and somehow the file's encoding got set to 'UCS-2 LE BOM' instead of the expected 'UTF-8'. Setting the encoding to UTF-8 and saving the file resolves the batch file issue.
I hit the same issue many years ago, so I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't think of that before posting.

PowerShell resolution:
I've recently starting using the SCCM module, and hadn't noticed that my script was setting my location to the "PS $SCCMsiteCode:>" PSDrive.
Simply typing 'c:' in the ISE console pane and hitting enter, allowed the script to return the expected results.
I didn't think the current location would prevent Write-Output from writing to the console pane.

Comment: But even UTF-8 has a BOM so you would still need to save it as UTF-8 without a BOM or the first computer will not be found.

Answer (score 0):

In case the loop doesn't work, add some debugging logic. At the moment the script fails silently in two cases: 1) `$Computers` is empty 2) `test-path` has unexpected problems.

When one works on console, it's a common mistake to initialize some variables and never assign those in the scripted version. To catch such, add `set-strictmode` to the script so that it will complain when an uninitialized variable is used.

```
set-strictmode -Version 2.0
# Prohibits references to uninitialized variables
# and references to non-existent properties of an object.
# This eliminates common typos

if($Computers.Length -le 0) { # Is there data to process?
    write-host '$Computers collection was empty!'
} 
if($Computers.GetType().name -ne "Object[]") { # Is the collection an array anyway?
    write-host '$Computers wasnt an array but: ' $Computers.GetType()
}
foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    if (Test-Path "\\$Computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name")
    {
        Write-Output "$($Computer): Folder Exists"
    } else { # test-path fails. Write a warning and the path tried
        write-host -nonewline "Fail: "
        write-host "test-path \\$Computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Folder Name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gives me the same result as what I posted.  
$Computers contains ~3k elements in a string array, and the typing is not an issue. Uninitialized variables are also not an issue in my code sample.

Comment: So, it doesn't give any output at all? If that's the case, start by printing the collection length before the first `if` block.

Comment: I'm already writing "$($Computers.count)" in my private version of the code.